# I am running an NGINX container that is serving up a PHP site, the site stops responding after a few days

Tags: docker, nginx, windows-container

When the site stops responding I need to restart the docker desktop application. This is on a windows server 2019 machine. When digging into the event logs the only errors I see are not really specific. I first get a .NET error saying there was a null exception followed by a generic application error docker.exe event ID 1000. I've ran the applications own diagnostic tool and it says it fails in connecting to some of the backend services. The thing that trips me up though is that it'll work for sometime after restarting the application. So it just starts to fail, there were a lot of different diagnostic files and was wondering what would be the best one to start with since it looks like there can be me many different things going on.

I've tried restarting the services and monitored for any resource constrains but everything on the host is okay, there are no crash events from event viewer, they all point to the docker on desktop application. (I know technically docker on desktop isn't supported but it had been working for months okay.)

```
[FAIL] DD0014: are the backend processes running? 3 errors occurred:
    * com.docker.backend.exe is not running
    * com.docker.vpnkit.exe is not running
    * com.docker.proxy.exe is not running


[PASS] DD0007: is the backend responding?
[PASS] DD0008: is the native API responding?
[FAIL] DD0009: is the vpnkit API responding? open \\.\pipe\dockerVpnKitDiagnostics: Access is denied.
[FAIL] DD0010: is the Docker API proxy responding? failed to ping Docker proxy API with error: Get "http://ipc/desktop-diagnostics/ping": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: As you mentioned, Docker Desktop is not supported for production (aka leave the app running for days and days, and have production workload on it). With that said, have you tried running this on a Windows Server with just the Docker engine (Docker CE)?